# Change carousel width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, carousel

I have a carousel that shows different types of images. They have different widths and heights. **I'm using bootstrap carousel.**

With the heights, there is no problem, it changes when the image showed changes. But with the width, it always has the same (too big than all the images, as you can see on the screenshot):

[image]

My carousel code is the next:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" margin: 0 auto">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterImages" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="carousel item <%# (Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "active" : "") %>">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("FileName") %>' runat="server" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas of what I have to do to have a width that changes depending on the image? Why it is changing the height but not the width?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide the css for the carousel?

Comment: i'm using bootstrap

Comment: try and solve it with your own CSS. If and when you run into problems ask here but try for yourself first

Comment: I ask because I try to do it before, but I don't have any good results and I post my best try...

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you actually using?

Comment: I'm using that https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases i think it is bootstrap 3

Comment: set image width:100% in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it adding this on my css:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing carousel height according to image height is a more common scenario whereas changing carousel width is more specific scenario. I think that is why it is implemented like this by default. And usually the best approach is to prepeare your images to have a same size hence in this case you don't have to care about changing carousel size.

However you can change carousel width using [Carousel Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events):

```
$('#carouselExampleControls').on('slid.bs.carousel', resizeCarousel);
$(document).ready(resizeCarousel);

function resizeCarousel(){
    var imgWidth = $('.carousel-item.active img').width();
    $('#carouselContainer').width(imgWidth);
}
```

See an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/g6e3v4o5/5/)

Comment: I try like you do, but it doesn't work, it still does the same

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap - inline style
`<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width: 80%;">`

or `class="carousel slide w-75"`